# How to use vim's syntax files in emacs to color the text

Tags: vim, emacs, syntax

Are there any snippets to make emacs use the .vim syntax files found in /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ for coloring text. Many applications like conky have the vim syntax files like "conkyrc.vim" for vim but not for emacs. So is there an easy way to use those files rather than rewriting a new language-mode for each of those available in vimfiles directory.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no generic way.